# vue,undefined "parse" when I want to use "acorn" and its parse to make AST

Tags: javascript, vue.js, abstract-syntax-tree, new-operator, acorn

My English is not good,sorry...
the code is formed by AI(I almost know nothing about vue)
I'm not sure whether I downloaded the "acorn" successfully
I use `pnpm install acorn` to download
I'm stuck in the problems for days
Each piece of code formed by AI will not run successfully

the codemirror box is correctly formed while when I type code in the box,the page will throw errors
and "acorn""esprima""espree" cannot work

```js
<template>
  <div class="ast-explorer">
    <div class="editor-pane">
      <textarea ref="codeEditor"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ast-pane">
      <pre>{{ astTree }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror'
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript'
import acorn from 'acorn'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      astTree: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initializeCodeMirror()
  },
  methods: {
    initializeCodeMirror() {
      this.codeEditor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this.$refs.codeEditor, {
        mode: 'javascript',
        lineNumbers: true
      })
      this.codeEditor.on('change', this.updateAST)
    },
    updateAST() {
      const code = this.codeEditor.getValue()
      this.astTree = JSON.stringify(acorn.parse(code), null, 2)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.ast-explorer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.editor-pane {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ast-pane {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
```

there is error information

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parse')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parse')
    at Proxy.updateAST (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/babel-loader@8.3.0_@babel+core@7.23.7_webpack@5.89.0/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/.pnpm/vue-loader@17.4.2_vue@3.4.15_webpack@5.89.0/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:32:83)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/codemirror@5.65.16/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:2679:23)
    at fireCallbacksForOps (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/codemirror@5.65.16/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:2629:22)
    at finishOperation (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/codemirror@5.65.16/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:2647:7)
    at endOperation (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/codemirror@5.65.16/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:4874:7)
    at runInOp (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/codemirror@5.65.16/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:5045:7)
    at TextareaInput.poll (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/codemirror@5.65.16/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:12280:5)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/.pnpm/codemirror@5.65.16/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:12023:13)
```

I doubt whether my pnpm has some problems
Thanks everyone help my problems

Comment: The error means that there's no default export in 'acorn'. Try to `import * as acorn from 'acorn'` and debug what `acorn` is if the problem persists. The way it works depends on your setup, which is unknown